# How to switch between chars and string

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am using the following code in an encryption program:

```
If File.Exists(filebox.Text) Then
    Dim text As String = File.ReadAllText(filebox.Text)
    Dim chars() As Char = text.ToCharArray
    Dim ascii(chars.Length - 1) As Integer
    For i = 0 To chars.Length - 1
        chars(i) = Chr(Asc(chars(i)) + 3 * 2)
    Next
    text = chars.ToString
    File.WriteAllText(filebox.Text, text)
    output("success")
Else
    output("file does not exist or is open")
End If
```

However, when I check the text file after, all I see is:

> System.Char[]

How can I make it show the other text instead?

Comment: chars,ToString() just doesn't do what you hope it does.  Consider New String(chars) instead.

Comment: Chr and Asc don't do what you think. Use ChrW and AscW if you must use VB4/VB5/VB6-era functions, or using .NET libraries, Convert.ToChar and Convert.ToInt32. But, it's pretty sketchy doing arithmetic on characters and expecting characters as a result. In many character sets, not all character codes represent defined characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
text = chars.ToString
```

To

```
text = New String(chars)
```

`chars` is an array and an you are doing `ToString` on that array.
However, you can create a `New String` that takes a `char` array as a parameter.

[`String(char[])`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttyxaek9(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) documentation.